# change kernel version manually in iso image

Tags: debian, kernel, iso

I had downloaded debian stretch iso image. i had generated my own customized kernel.whether is there any possibility to replace inbuilt kernel with my customized kernel and generate new iso image with customized kernel.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. 
Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named 
["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). 
And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). 
You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You obviously can rebuild your ISO image.
Read [How to modify an existing CD image](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify/CD) or [DebianCustomCD](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianCustomCD)